# How to use Global variables in Ranorex?

Tags: ranorex

I need to create and use global variable as optional parameter, but do not know how I can implement it.

I created the global variable in Ranorex studio:

[image]

Also this variable appeared in **`Data binding`** tag:

[image]

But I can't use this variable in the code. (`ASECore` package do not contains any parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global Variables in Ranorex Record module or Ranorex Code module. Let me please first make an introduction of how to use them.

### **Create in Record module**

In the Record module, click button Variables... in the top right corner and add the variables you want to use in the redord module.

[image]

Then use them in your recording:
[image]

---

### **Create in Code module**

When you create a code module, it will look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of MyCode.
/// </summary>
[TestModule("32310FEC-5336-4F83-B448-ABC851EE5731", ModuleType.UserCode, 1)]
public class MyCode : ITestModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new instance.
    /// </summary>
    public MyCode()
    {
        // Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the playback of actions in this module.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>You should not call this method directly, instead pass the module
    /// instance to the <see cref="TestModuleRunner.Run(ITestModule)"/> method
    /// that will in turn invoke this method.</remarks>
    void ITestModule.Run()
    {
        Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 300;
        Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 100;
        Delay.SpeedFactor = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Now, right click in the code and choose "Insert new module variable". Then you can set a name and default value. Press ok and it will add something like this:

```
string _MyVariable = "DefaultValue";
[TestVariable("de0fb4a9-32ba-4635-8f0f-4ff6db184c3f")]
public string MyVariable
{
    get { return _MyVariable; }
    set { _MyVariable = value; }
}
```

Now, you can use the variables in the run method like normal C# properties:

```
repo.Calculator.CalculatorResults.PressKeys(Input_1);
repo.Calculator.PlusButton.Click();
repo.Calculator.CalculatorResults.PressKeys(Input_2);
repo.Calculator.EqualButton.Click();
```

### **How to bind Variables in Suite**

When you created the global parameters, it's true that you can not bind them on the suite level.
[image]

Therefore close the dialog and right click on the Record/Code module and choose "Data binding"
[image]

In the lower table you can bind your variables of the Record/Code module to the global variables. If they have the same name, you can also Auto-bind them.

When you now execute the test suite, the values of the global variables will be used in test. If you execute the Record/Code module standalone, then the default values will be used in test.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set that variable in your highest node, you can use it and assign variables to it in lower nodes. So when you make a smart folder in your test suite and go to the data binding, you will notice the global is present under the parameters. All you need to do is make a recording with a variable that will use the global variable and link it in that folder.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I still do not understand. 1) I created the global variable 2) I try to bind this variable with the Record - I clicks right mouse button on the Record - I see the "TestCase properties" window and the global variable in it, but I still can't handle this variable in the code.